# Reusing of component.html in more than 2 .ts file

Tags: angular

So, I have a project in angular and there are many components which have same UI interface but not exactly same , so I wanted to use a common html file for those and make the different .ts files for the functionality , an I am rendering the component pages using router, so is it possible to do so

can any one help me with this, or any example how to achieve that. the component consist of a table, with some button with basic crud and filter functionalities with API interactions

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what a component is.  You can include a component inside any other component.  Make a new component that has your table and whatever else in it, and then include that component on the two (or more) page components that you need it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the html and some logic to a shared component and use it in the 2 components using inputs and outputs.

Comment: okey but if we refresh the page the existing data like ids or some variable will go of I don't want that I want to still l have that data after refreshing the page, so that's why I am not using shared component or service

Comment: You can use a template